# How to play this chord?

Tags: piano, chords, beats

This is a simplified version of Schumann's *Träumerei* (Op.15 no.7) , toward the end. How to play the left hand chord pointed to by the red arrow? How does it differ from just the original version without the upper B (orange arrow)?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an error. Did this come from MuseScore?

Comment: @Aaron Yes: https://musescore.com/user/4801191/scores/1230731  Can you spot other errors there? ;-)

Comment: OT: Rather than playing a simplified arrangement — why not play the original and adapt parts you struggle with? This way you‘ll get a better understanding of the piece and you won‘t have to relearn the whole thing when you move on to the real thing in the future.

Comment: @Lazy Good idea! I will give it a try. Btw, anyone has opinion the comparison in difficulty levels between this piece and Mendelssohn's Sweet Remembrance (Op. 19 No. 1), original scores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an error. The arranger either included it accidentally or intended it to be one octave higher.

In either case, a better option would be to make it an F, so the left-hand chord would become, from bottom to top, G-B-F.

Comment: Thanks. The original is impossible for hand not big enough.

Comment: @GrandAdagio There are a variety of ways to accommodate that chord, particularly since it is both rolled and pedaled. The roll can be quite slow, too.

Comment: @AaronThanks. I usually don't like to learn simplified versions, but this original is too hard for me. I'll try the original chords whenever possible...

Comment: @GrandAdagio Yes, the original is quite challenging. It's considered an early advanced piece.

Comment: @GrandAdagio Many pianists will have difficulties playing those three notes simultaneously without sufficient preparation (while playing and in practicing). It's not just a matter of skills, but hand size. Most people isn't able to instantly play more than a ninth alone, which becomes even more difficult when adding a further note. While the "original" version you provided also uses the "arpeggio" line, most real original versions don't have it. Still, also considering the musical era of the piece, playing it as slight arpeggio will not be completely wrong (nor make it a "simplified version").

Comment: @GrandAdagio Remember that rhythm is not just about strict tempo, but about time relations: note lengths don't have absolute durations, but relative ones. Many instruments have their own performance practice styles that *do* require some "time stretching" (for example, classical guitar performances may result a bit odd sometimes), which is typical for the instrument and established as common practice for it. Also, a fermata leaves a lot of freedom to the musician taste, especially when playing solo. You may even play, in order: the bass G, the higher A, and then, freely, the remaining notes.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks, really appreciate your comments.

Comment: It _could_ be played g-g-b (so with a repeated g), but it’s not likely.